# Parsing and replacing columns in a file

Tags: bash, oracle, python-2.7, awk

**INPUT:**

I have an input file in which the first 10 characters of each line represent 2 fields - first 4 characters(field A) and the next 6 characters(field B). The file contains about 400K records.

I have a Mapping table which contains about 25M rows and looks like

```
Field A Field B SomeStringA SomeStringB
1628    836791   1234        783901
afgd    ahutwe   1278        ashjkl
--------------------------------
--------------------------------
```

and so on.

Field A and Field B combined is the *Primary Key* for the table.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

*Replace:*

```
Field A by SomeStringA
Field B by SomeStringB
```

in the input file. SomeStringA and SomeStringB are exactly the same width as Field A and B respectively.

Here's what I'm trying:

Approach 1:

1. Sort and Dump the mapping table into a file

   ```
   spool dump_file
   select * from mapping order by fieldA, fieldB;
   spool off
   exit;
   ```
2. Strip the input file and get the first 10 chars

   ```
   cut -c1-10 input_file >  input_file_stripped
   ```
3. Do something to find the lines that begin with the same string and then when they do - replace in the input_file with field 10-20 in the spooled file. - here's where I'm stuck.

Approach 2:

1. Take the input file and get the first 10 chars

   ```
   cut -c1-10 input_file >input_file_stripped
   ```
2. Use `sqlldr` and load into a temp_table.
3. Select matching records from the mapping table and spool

   ```
   spool matching_records
   select m.* from mapping m, temp t where m.fieldA=t.fieldA and m.fieldB=t.fieldB;
   spool off
   exit;
   ```
4. Now how do I replace these in the original file ?

Given the high number of records to process, how can this be done and done fast ?

Notes:

1. Not a one time activity, has to be done daily so scale is important
2. The mapping table is unlikely to change
3. I've Python, shell script and Oracle database available. Any combination of these is fine.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Can you give some actual sample lines to get a better picture? Are the replacement lines part of a separate file ?

Comment: The replacement strings are in a mapping table. I can dump them to a file if needed

Comment: @Inian added sample lines and more details